# Need a Good PDF Viewer

Tags: windows, pdf-viewer

I am looking for a good, minimalist PDF viewer. If it has a feature that blocks distractions while reading, that would be great as well.

It should run on Windows 10 and if it's Open Source then even better.

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. Especially missing: what OS should it run on, how much may it cost. Please **[edit]** your question to include those details, so we can give good & matching recommendations. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[Sumatra](https://www.sumatrapdfreader.org) is one of the very popular free opensources ones with a very simple interface. The code can be found [here](https://github.com/sumatrapdfreader/sumatrapdf). I have been using Sumatra for a while without issues.

Additionally, if you search this forum, you will find other answers as the question has been asked a few times in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried **Xodo**? I bet you will like it since you want something minimal, yet powerful.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/xodo-pdf-view-edit-and-annotate/9wzdncrdjxp4

Also check it in Google Play/App Store for your other devices, if you like.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There is a Windows port of the Linux PDF reader "Evince". It's a port of the Gnome 2 version, so is nice and basic compared to, say, a Gnome 3 application. And as you requested, it is open-source.

I've been using it since October 2017 on Windows 10 without many problems. In fact, the only problems I've encountered have been in the last two weeks, when multiple copies of the same document have been opened and I've tried to close them using the Windows 10 taskbar.

The most recent version for Windows is 2.32.0.145.

The original download link was

https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evince/Downloads

The .msi file has now been taken down from there, but you can still get it by going to:

https://web.archive.org/web/20171107025414/https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evince/Downloads

Windows 10 is not listed in the supported OS versions, but as I say, it still worked for me for over four years on Win 10.

When you've downloaded the .msi, check the md5sum to make sure it downloaded OK - it should be:

02b5ac628870c9c8480433223cf22425